# applicationhost.config is beeing changed every time I reopen Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, iis-express

I am creating asp.net-mvc application and I use port forwarding to be able to test my project from the outside. But every single time I reopen and build my application IIS-Express changes applicationhost.config and everyting i can see is error.

File before reopening:

```
        <site name="Project" id="2">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="path" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:61035:*" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
```

File after:

```
        <site name="Project" id="2">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="path" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:61035:*" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
        <site name="Project(1)" id="3">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="path" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:61035:localhost" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
```

And as you may expect, Project(1) is beeing hosted by IIS-Express and I have to change binding to `*:61035:*` each time I reopen Visual Studio, because it keeps adding another site, and ignores previous ones.

Is there anything I can do with it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a really simple solution to this.

I only had to change:

```
<site name="Project" id="2">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="path" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:61035:*" />
    </bindings>
</site>
```

to:

```
<site name="Project" id="2">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="path" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:61035:*" />
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:61035:localhost" />
    </bindings>
</site>
```

Now everything works well, and I don't have to edit this file every time I reopen Visual Studio.

Comment: Useful help! I had to add one new line for each extra binding with different ports, leaving the existing ones as they were.